# Entity Framework Linq to Object Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have one problem.

Database Shema

```
==================
|parts           |
==================
| partId |textId |
==================

========================
texts                  |
========================
|TextId|LanguageId|text|
========================

============================
languages                  |
============================
|LanguageId|LanguageIsoCode|
============================
```

I want to map this result to the following object

```
public long PartId { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string,string> Name { get; set; }
```

eg.

```
{
  PartId: 32020
  Name: {["en": "Blah", "es": "Blah2"]}
}
```

this is what I have tried, but Im running into TimeOut with this query.

```
var query = (from p in _context.epc_parts
         select new //select first dynamic object
         {
             PartId = p.PartID,
             Code = p.PartName,
             Name = (from trans in _context.epc_texts
                     join lang in _context.epc_languages on trans.LanguageID equals lang.LanguageID
                     where p.TextID == trans.TextID
                     select new
                     {
                         LanguageId = lang.shortname.ToLower(),
                         Caption = trans.Caption
                     })

         }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SearchPartModel //transform it here when we can use dictionary
         {
             Code = x.Code,
             PartId = x.PartId,
             Name = x.Name.ToDictionary(t => t.LanguageId, t => t.Caption)
         });
```

The parts table has about 60k rows for every row there are 7 translations. Navigation properties cant be used because the Shema doesn't use foreign keys and the model is generated from db.

Comment: Why you use `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()` I believe if you do a ToList it will execute the query and transform will do in memory. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Also try to use `NavigationProperty` instead of join

Comment: How many records are you expecting ?

Comment: Well there's no filter/where condition so you are basically loading the entire schema you have presented.  If this is a web page and there is a lot of data, a timeout is not unexpected.

Comment: @Eldho, ToList() does execute the query.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it with this query. For the whole query it took about 20s to load everything what is ok for this purpose. Im using group by first.

```
(from p in _context.epc_parts
                     join trans in _context.epc_texts on p.TextID equals trans.TextID
                     join lang in _context.epc_languages on trans.LanguageID equals lang.LanguageID
                     select new
                     {
                         PartId = p.PartID,
                         Code = p.PartName,
                         Caption = trans.Caption,
                         LanguageId = lang.shortname.ToLower()
                     }).AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.PartId).Select(g => new SearchPartModel
                     {
                         Code = g.Select(x => x.Code).FirstOrDefault(),
                         PartId = g.Key,
                         Name = g.Select(x => new
                         {
                             x.LanguageId,
                             x.Caption
                         }).Distinct().ToDictionary(y => y.LanguageId, y => y.Caption)
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from p in _context.epc_parts
join trans in _context.epc_texts on p.TextID equals trans.TextID
join lang in _context.epc_languages on trans.LanguageID equals lang.LanguageID

select new {   
             PartId = p.PartID,
             Code = p.PartName,
             Name = new
                 {
                     LanguageId = lang.shortname.ToLower(),
                     Caption = trans.Caption
                 }

}
```

That should be better, otherwise in your current implementation for each `part` you're querying the `texts` table

Comment: With that query I won't get a Dictionary<string,string> for the translations as I wan't. How to get a dictionary of all translations in a single object as described in the question.

Comment: yes, but you can do the same thing you're doing to convert it into a dictionary, I thought the main problem was the timing out issue